# How do I use the numpy longdouble dtype?

Tags: python, numpy, cython, long-double

I am trying to work with the `np.longdouble` dtype in my Python code, and am trying to use NumPy to manipulate long doubles that I get from a C module compiled with Cython.

Suppose I do this:

```
import numpy as np

print np.finfo(np.longdouble)
Machine parameters for float128
---------------------------------------------------------------------
precision= 18   resolution= 1e-18
machep=   -63   eps=        1.08420217249e-19
negep =   -64   epsneg=     5.42101086243e-20
minexp=-16382   tiny=       3.36210314311e-4932
maxexp= 16384   max=        1.18973149536e+4932
nexp  =    15   min=        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------------


a = np.longdouble(1e+346)

a
Out[4]: inf

b = np.longdouble(1e+347)

b
Out[6]: inf

c = a/b
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/start_ipython_kernel.py:1:
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in longdouble_scalars
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

c
Out[8]: nan

a.dtype, b.dtype, c.dtype
Out[9]: (dtype('float128'), dtype('float128'), dtype('float128'))
```

In essence, it is linked to the same issue as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536820/numpy-longdouble-arithmetic-does-not-seem-to-be-in-long-double-with-conversion) question and I understand that Python first converts the `1e+346` into a float, whose represntation would be `inf`. However, can someone suggest a workaround? Is there a way to create NumPy longdoubles that are not converted to floats first?

I have a C module that can output long doubles, which I want to use in a numpy array of dtype `np.longdouble`.

Even if the solution involves re-compiling Python/NumPy, I am willing to try it.

Comment: Might still be unsupported, see e.g. http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/longdouble-float96-literals-td1841.html

Answer (score 7):

There are a few things you might want to take into account.

First, this is a mess. NumPy knows `longdouble` and `float128`. Unfortunately, the names are misleading, the underlying implementation is C long double, which is usually (but not necessarily always) an 80-bit float. (Actually you can see it here by looking at "precision"; 18 digits is approximately 60 bits, and the 80-bit float has 64 bits in its mantissa. The precision would be around 34 digits if real 128-bit floats were used.)

There may not be any direct way to pass long doubles as arguments to a C function, but if you pass pointers instead, then you can avoid the problem. For example, you may pass your array data as `uint8` (by using `myarray.view(dtype='uint8')`) and the cast the pointer to the buffer into long double * in your C program. At least then Python has nothing to do with type conversions. (Most probably you do not need to take the `view` because you are, after all, only exporting a pointer to the array buffer.)

Just beware that this trick relies on the compiler having the same kind of type settings when compiling Python and your C program. In addition to precision differences, there may be byte order differences (rarely if the programs run in the same machine) and alignment differences. My Python seems to align the `longdouble` items at 16 byte borders (i.e. there is always 6 bytes of zeros per each element), but the C compiler may use 10/12/16 byte alignment.

As far as I know, the details are implementation specific. So, this is doable but requires some extra care and there may be portability issues.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! I actually don't mind the inputs to the C function to be normal doubles. However, I do want the output to be treated as a long double. I guess I will think of other ways of doing it by taking logarithm or so (it is not so much the precision I want as much as the range)

Comment: With a bit of luck, you can create the array easily just by using the C long double type. However, if you bump into alignment problems, then it becomes stickier.