# How to get a Python long double literal?

Tags: python, numpy, long-double

How to get a Python long double literal? I have tried with

```
numpy.longdouble(1e309)
```

and

```
numpy.longdouble("1e309")
```

but both of them just return `inf`. What would be the right way to do that?

[**EDIT**] An answer below says that long double is treated as double in some platform. It is not the case on my system. To show this, I have tried:

```
np.longdouble(2.0)**1029
```

on my system (Mac OS 10.11).  It returns

```
5.7526180315594109047e+309
```

[**EDIT2**] As suggested, I just tried

```
 np.finfo(np.longdouble)
```

which gives

```
 finfo(resolution=1e-18, 
       min=-1.18973149536e+4932, 
       max=1.18973149536e+4932, 
       dtype=float128)
```

on my OS.  For info, my numpy version is 1.10.1.

Comment: Seems like it is somewhat duplicate of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536820/numpy-longdouble-arithmetic-does-not-seem-to-be-in-long-double-with-conversion

Comment: What NumPy version are you on? It looks like this [may have been fixed](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4381) on August 28, 2015, so the latest version of NumPy should have the fix. I don't have access to a 1.10 install to check at the moment.

Comment: @user2357112 numpy version 1.10.1.

Answer (score 3):

Version 2 works now (numpy 1.19.1, machine: x86-64):

```py
>>> np.longdouble('1e309')
1e+309
```

The other one doesn't.

```py
>>> np.longdouble(1e309)
inf
```

This doesn't work because 1e309 is first interpreted by the python interpreter, which converts it into a 64 bit floating point number (because it doesn't know any better) and THEN send it to numpy. You have to give numpy the number in form of a string literal to give it a chance to process the number itself.

^ x86-64 means essentially any personal computer running Windows, MacOS or Linux. I believe it should work on all of them, because as far as i know x86-64 all have the x87 floating point unit that natively supports 80 bit floats.

Answer (score 2):

On some platforms `long double` is essential the same as `double`. From [numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/c-api.dtype.html):

> NPY_LONGDOUBLE
>
> The enumeration value for a platform-specific floating
>   point type which is at least as large as NPY_DOUBLE, but larger on
>   many platforms.

Sometimes long double is a 80-bit float (but not 128 bit, as many people would expect).
You may check with:

```
numpy.finfo(numpy.longdouble)
```

Consider the following answers as well:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25481654/2370124
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18537604/2370124

You may also try this:

```
n = numpy.longdouble(1e300) * 1e9
```

Comment: The problem [still shows up](http://ideone.com/tY5wJn) even when `numpy.longdouble` really is extended precision, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem remains unsolved, however.

Comment: Why don't just use numpy.longdouble(10.0)**309?

Comment: When I check with `numpy.finfo(numpy.longdouble)` how do I tell from the result whether I have the 80-bit or 128-bit float?